# Handler for a control to pan a map in four directions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, user-interface

I have a pan control that look like this:

[image: pan control]

Pretty standard Google Mapsish controls, IMO.

When the user clicks in the top 3rd of the control, it should pan up (deltaY = +1); right third means it should pan east (deltaX = -1); Down is deltaY = -1, and West is deltaX = +1. The control is 50px, square. I have working code, but I believe it can be written much more elegantly than this using a single (if discontinuous) mathematical function.

```
$(control).click(function (evt) {
    var clickPointX = (evt.layerX || evt.offsetX),
        clickPointY = (evt.layerY || evt.offsetY),
        deltaX,
        deltaY;

    // control is 50x50 px.
    // Click in the top third, get a positive 'Y' value.
    // Click in the left third, get a positive 'X' value.
    // Click in the middle, get zero.
    if (clickPointX < 16) {
        deltaX = +1;
    } else if (clickPointX > 34) {
        deltaX = -1;
    } else {
        deltaX = 0;
    }

    if (clickPointY < 16) {
        deltaY = +1;
    } else if (clickPointY > 34) {
        deltaY = -1;
    } else {
        deltaY = 0;
    }
    map.panDirection(deltaX, deltaY);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few improvements:

- replace magic numbers
- extract repetition into a function
- dynamically calculate dimensions

Example code:

```js
function getDelta(clickPoint, controlDimension, threshold){
    var delta;
    if (clickPoint < threshold) {
        delta = +1;
    } else if (clickPoint > controlDimension- threshold) {
        delta = -1;
    } else {
        delta = 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var control = $('#example');
    var controlHeight = control.height();
    var controlWidth = control.width();
    var widthThreshold = controlHeight/3;
    var heightThreshold = controlWidth/3;
    
    $(control).click(function (evt) {
        var clickPointX = (evt.layerX || evt.offsetX);
        var clickPointY = (evt.layerY || evt.offsetY);
        var deltaX = getDelta(clickPointX, controlWidth, widthThreshold);
        var deltaY = getDelta(clickPointY, controlHeight, heightThreshold);
        alert('delta x: ' + deltaX + '\n' + 'delta y: ' + deltaY);
        //map.panDirection(deltaX, deltaY);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <div id='example' style='background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px;' />
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want less repetition, you can do this.
But I don't think there's anything wrong with your
approach (which is more efficient incidentally).

```
var pan = function(clickx, clicky){
    var delta = function(val){
        return val < 16 ? 1 :
               val > 34 ? -1 :
               0;
    };
    return {dx: delta(clickx), dy: delta(clicky)};
};
```

I do think you should separate out the click handling
and the panning algorithm into separate functions unless efficiency
then becomes an issue.

Comment: You're right. I will probably do that, I just wanted to see if this could be made into a simple discontinuous mathematical function first.

Comment: What I've written is a simple discontinuous mathematical function :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably more of a personal preference but i find three sections to an `if` hard to read.

I would set your Delta values to 0 initially

```
var deltaX = 0;
```

then you can remove:

```
} else {
    deltaX = 0;
}
```

and you have three less lines to read. Not a real performance improvement or anything though.